# How to access redux variables and functions from deep components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I'm a bit confused about redux implementation.

Let's say my app has this component structure:

```
-App
--ProfilationStep
---ProfilationStep1
----React-Select (http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/)
```

I need to use redux because the app is going to grow bigger and deeper, so I started by setting up Actions, Reducers and Action types for the React-Select component. I also set the mapStateToProps in the App.js file.

**Now I need to know how to pass/access the data stored in redux to other components (React-Select for example) and how to edit it with the actions I declared.**

This is my **index.js** file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import  ProfilationSelectReducer  from './components/reducers/profilationSelect';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = createStore(
    ProfilationSelectReducer
    );

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

This is my **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import Profilation from './components/Profilation'
import ProfilationStep from './components/Profilation/ProfilationStep'

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as SelectActionCreators from './components/actions/profilationSelect'
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    steps: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {

    console.log(this.props)
    const { dispatch, steps } = this.props;
    const changeValue= bindActionCreators(SelectActionCreators.changeValue, dispatch);

   const stepComponents = this.props.steps.map((step, index) => (
      <ProfilationStep
        key={index}
        index={index}
        step={step}
      />
    ));

   return (
      <div className="repower-app">

       { stepComponents }
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  steps:state.steps
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

This is my **ProfilationStep.js** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ProfilationStep1 from './ProfilationStep1'
import ProfilationStep2 from './ProfilationStep2'
import ProfilationStep3 from './ProfilationStep3'
import ProfilationStep4 from './ProfilationStep4'
import ProfilationStep5 from './ProfilationStep5'


const ProfilationStep = props =>

<div className='ProfilationStep'>
    {props.index===0 &&
        <ProfilationStep1 
            step={props.step}
        />
    }
    {props.stepIndex===2 &&
        <ProfilationStep2
        handleSelect={props.handleSelect} 
        handleInput={props.handleInput} 
        expend={props.expend}
        period={props.period}
        light={props.light}
        gas={props.gas}
        />
    }
    {props.stepIndex===3 &&
        <ProfilationStep3
        handleSelect={props.handleSelect} 
        environment={props.environment} 
        />
    }

    {props.stepIndex===4 &&
        <ProfilationStep4 
            flexibility={props.flexibility}
            handleSelect={props.handleSelect} 
        />
    }
    {props.stepIndex===5 &&
        <ProfilationStep5 
            customize={props.customize}
            handleSelect={props.handleSelect} 
        />
    }

</div>

export default ProfilationStep
```

This is my **ProfilationStep1.js** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

var jobOptions = [
  { value: 'edilizia', label: 'Edilizia' },
  { value: 'editoria', label: 'Editoria' },
  { value: 'educazione', label: 'Educazione' }
];



const ProfilationStep1 = props => 

<div className='ProfilationStep'>
    La mia attivit&agrave; si occupa di <Select
                  name="job"
                  value={props.step.job}
                  onChange={e => props.changeValue(e.target.value)}
                  options={jobOptions}
                  />    

</div>

ProfilationStep1.propTypes = {

    //isComplete: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    //isActive: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    job: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    service: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    handleSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default ProfilationStep1
```

This is my **reducer**

```
import * as ProfilationSelectActionTypes from '../actiontypes/profilationSelect';

const initialState = {


    steps: [{
        job: "",
        service: ""
    }],
}

export default function ProfilationSelectReducer (state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ProfilationSelectActionTypes.CHANGE_VALUE:
        return {
            ...state,
            steps:[{
                job: action.value
            }]

        };
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

This is my **actiontypes** file

```
export const CHANGE_VALUE ='profilationSelect/CHANGE_VALUE';
```

and, finally, this is my **actions** file

```
import * as ProfilationSelectActionTypes from '../actiontypes/profilationSelect';

export const changeValue = value =>{
    return{
        type: ProfilationSelectActionTypes.CHANGE_VALUE,
        value
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right way.

The solution is simple: You bind your state to the react props. With the props, you can do whatever you like (e.g. pass them to react-select). If you want to modify it, you have to map "mapDispatchToProps", where you map functions, which execute your actions to the props. This works the same as "mapStateTopProps":

End of App.js (import your actions file on top, named "profilationSelectActions" here):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  steps:state.steps
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateJobValue: (value) => dispatch(profilationSelectActions.changeValue(value))
}

// Also add here mapDispatchToProps
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Now the function "updateJobValue" is available in the props of your app.js. You can now easily pass it down to your components and to the onChange event of react-select:

In your ProfilationStep1.js change this line:

```
onChange={e => props.changeValue(e.target.value)}
```

To this (after you passed the function updateJobValue down)

```
onChange{e => props.updateJobType(e.target.value)}
```

After that, updateJobType should go all the way up to App.js and then dispatch the action. After that, the application will re-render with the new steps.